# How to update my fragment UI outside of onCreateView()?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update my fragemnt UI after my fragment is initialized after I get data from my database. How can I input this data onto my UI? Previously, I was doing it in onCreateView() where I can edit my view through accessing a layout xml file. However, I want to call a separate function to edit the view once my database gives me the data. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'm not passing any data from my activity. All data is coming from my fragment itself.

I tried to create a new method to edit the view but I have no way of passing in the container needed to inflate the view.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using databinding or viewbinding with viewmodels

[view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

[data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

[binding with viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture)